# Android design guidelines - List action button

Tags: android, listview

Currently I expose actions to item in a listview using long click to popup an alert dialog. The new android design guidelines for lists seem to recommend a button at the end of the list item. Is there a standard drawable available in the sdk for this button and any established behaviour for how the menu is presented? I would like to fit in since that is half the point but none of the apps I use have implemented this pattern.

http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html

Comment: I was also hoping for a built in way to accomplish this design pattern, with the border to the left of the action button.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a standard drawable available in the sdk for this button and any established behaviour for how the menu is presented?"

No, sorry.

Comment: Here is hoping we randomly all do it the same way then.

Answer (score 0):

That page does not say one way or another.  however on another Android design page they show the long press as an acceptable selection technique.  So I recommend you keep using the long press.  It is not against the new design guidelines.  [See Long Press guideline](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html)

Comment: I think you can still use it for contextual action bars but I would prefer not to. Based on the feedback I get users don't understand long presses and I think it is better to switch to something more visually obvious.

Comment: I understand the point about user not understanding, however I was mainly pointing out the new design guidelines don't recommend using a button at the end of a list item.  The only place I saw anything about selecting was where I posted the link to.